# Strictness of dataToTag argument

Tags: haskell, ghc

In `GHC.Prim`, we find a magical function named [dataToTag#](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.5.0.0/docs/GHC-Prim.html#v:dataToTag-35-):

```
dataToTag# :: a -> Int#
```

It turns a value of any type into an integer based on the data constructor it uses. This is used to speed up derived implementations of `Eq`, `Ord`, and `Enum`. In the GHC source, the [docs for `dataToTag#`](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/564a31f32e522398c50828bcf35cf8deeec5e654/compiler/prelude/primops.txt.pp#L2687) explain that the argument should already by evaluated:

> The dataToTag# primop should always be applied to an evaluated argument.
>   The way to ensure this is to invoke it via the 'getTag' wrapper in GHC.Base:
>
> ```
> getTag :: a -> Int#
> getTag !x = dataToTag# x
> ```

It makes total sense to me that we need to force `x`'s evaluation before `dataToTag#` is called. What I do not get is why the bang pattern is sufficient. The definition of `getTag` is just syntactic sugar for:

```
getTag :: a -> Int#
getTag x = x `seq` dataToTag# x
```

But let's turn to the [docs for seq](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.5.0.0/docs/GHC-Prim.html#v:seq):

> A note on evaluation order: the expression `seq a b` does not guarantee that a will be evaluated before b. The only guarantee given by seq is that the both a and b will be evaluated before seq returns a value. In particular, this means that b may be evaluated before a. If you need to guarantee a specific order of evaluation, you must use the function pseq from the "parallel" package.

In the `Control.Parallel` module from the `parallel` package, the docs [elaborate further](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parallel-3.2.1.1/docs/Control-Parallel.html):

> ... seq is strict in both its arguments, so the compiler may, for example, rearrange `` a `seq` b `` into `` b `seq` a `seq` b `` ...

How is it that `getTag` is guaranteed to behave work, given that `seq` is insufficient for controlling evaluation order?

Comment: Are you certain that BangPatterns simply translate to that use of `seq`? The docs show that an extra `case` expression is also added.

Comment: @ElliotCameron, there's some funny magic around there that I don't really understand. They both compile to Core `case` expressions, but there's some monkey business to allow them to match a `seq` on the left-hand side of a rewrite rule.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

GHC tracks certain information about each primop. One key datum is whether the primop "can_fail". The original meaning of this flag is that a primop can fail if it can cause a hard fault. For example, array indexing can cause a segmentation fault if the index is out of range, so indexing operations can fail.

If a primop can fail, GHC will restrict certain transformations around it, and in particular won't float it out of any `case` expressions. It would be rather bad, for example, if

```
if n < bound
then unsafeIndex c n
else error "out of range"
```

were compiled to

```
case unsafeIndex v n of
  !x -> if n < bound
        then x
        else error "out of range"
```

One of these bottoms is an exception; the other is a segfault.

`dataToTag#` is marked can_fail. So GHC sees (in Core) something like

```
getTag = \x -> case x of
           y -> dataToTag# y
```

(Note that `case` is strict in Core.) Because `dataToTag#` is marked can_fail, it won't be floated out of any `case` expressions.